# Shift listView tiles?

Tags: c#, .net, listview

I have been attempting to understand the tiled listView in c#.net for weeks now with no succession.

I have shrunk my form's height/width (154x154) to the same tile size as the picture(s) (items with pictures) in my listView (which is docked in the form2); when my form2 is shown, you see item[0] in the listView...that is it! (which I want so far, so good!)

I have set the scrollable property to false to do away with both scrollbars (works perfectly fine so far...)

I have hooked both the left and right arrow keys GLOBALLY (which works as it has been thoroughly debugged) and when clicking the RIGHT arrow key, it should VERTICALLY bring up item[1], and so fourth.

The LEFT arrow key would bring up the previous item till it hits 0.

I have tried the following, but it does NOTHING.

```
private void HotkeyHandler(int i)
    {
        {
            if (this.listView1.InvokeRequired)
            {
                SetHotkeyCallback p = new SetHotkeyCallback(HotkeyHandler);
                this.Invoke(p, new object[] { i });
            }
            else
            {
                switch (i)
                {
                    case 1:
                        listView1.View = View.List;

                        if (listView1.TopItem.Index > 0)
                        {
                            listView1.TopItem = listView1.Items[listView1.TopItem.Index - 1];
                        }

                        listView1.View = View.Tile;
                        break;

                    case 2:
                        listView1.View = View.List;

                        if (listView1.TopItem.Index < listView1.Items.Count)
                        {
                            listView1.TopItem = listView1.Items[listView1.TopItem.Index + 1];
                        }

                        listView1.View = View.Tile;
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Please help me, I been loosing my mind for weeks now.

EDIT: The switch within the function above does go off, I have debugged it; therefore, it is not the invoking that is the problem...

Comment: Why do you switch between List and Tile View all the time ? Why at all?

Comment: I have read that if you set scrollable to false & it is a tile, you must switch to list to even set topitem (which is clearly not even working...)

Comment: Where did you read that? However [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.listview.topitem%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) says: _Setting this property has no effect when the Scrollable property value is false_

Comment: @TaW, I have read many articles that either said this or other things...It has been weeks of me either; making custom controls, doing hackery @ above, or just generally doing other stuff.

Clearly I don't have an answer for you and am seeking help...

Comment: I have tried stuff like; ensureVisible, etc.

Comment: There may be system function in the API that hides the scrollbars, but I don't go there, unless I really need to. So I can only offer a workaround. I think it is solid and not hackish at all. Layout Panels are not evil; in WPF stacks of them are the bread and butter. Here we need only one..

Comment: If you're only ever displaying **ONE** item a time, have you considered not using a ListView at all?  You could simply use a PictureBox and a Label, or build a UserControl that has both those controls in it.  You could still store the images in an ImageList, then build a simple Class to hold the ImageKey and Text of your "item".  Then have a List of your Items and update the UI accordingly when you change the current item.

Comment: @Idle_Mind I would love to create a custom ImageList with contextmenustrip inside it, but I don't know how to add it for each item within the imagelist...this would be much easier!

Comment: You can certainly customize a ContextMenuStrip based on the "current item" of anything.  Just store the relevant information about each item, then change the menus at run-time accordingly in the [Opening](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripdropdown.opening(v=vs.110).aspx) event of the menu.

Comment: In other words, you'd use the **same** ContextMenuStrip for all of the items and simply change what is displayed in it based on the current one.

Comment: @TaW, ANSWER WORKS FINE WHEN LISTVIEW IS NOT DOCKED IN PARENT CONTAINER!

Comment: If it works it works. But Idle's suggestion came to my mind as well.. so maybe something to consider next time.

Comment: yes will consider it may go with that in end. yours works so perfectly though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do it directly.

The way to get rid of the `ScrollBars`  is indeed to set `Scrollable = false;`. 
But that means what it says: Now the `ListView` will **not** scroll.

Here is a common workaround for many scrolling issues:
Place the `Listview` in a `Panel` and make it as large as needed to show all `Items`.

Then in order to scroll simply **move** the `LV` up and down:

```
private void prepare_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // we sit inside a Panel
    listView1.Parent = panel1;
    // initially they have the same size
    listView1.Size = panel1.Size;
    listView1.Location = Point.Empty;
    // a few test items
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        listView1.Items.Add("Item " + i);
    // now grow the height to display all items:
    int cols = listView1.Width / listView1.TileSize.Width;
    listView1.Height = (listView1.Items.Count / cols) * listView1.TileSize.Height;
}

// moving the LV up looks like scrolling down..
private void scrollDown_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listView1.Top -= listView1.TileSize.Height;
    if (listView1.Bottom < panel1.Height) 
        listView1.Top = -listView1.Height + panel1.Height;
}


// moving the LV down looks like scrolling up..
private void scrollUp_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listView1.Top += listView1.TileSize.Height;
    if (listView1.Top > 0) listView1.Top = 0;
}
```

Comment: My form is set to 154x154 and the listview is docked within the form which is set at 154x154.

Now, when my listView is generated (after filling the items), item[0] is shown without a scrollbar (it is a picture that size is 154x154)

Ill try this and get back to you...

Comment: It does work here. How does it 'not work'? Also: You may have a lot of things in your code after all those tries.. (E.g.: Make sure the ListView is no longer set Dock=fill; Dock the Panel instead.. !)

Comment: IT WORKS! OMFG! I LUV U! I CAN KISS U! I WANNA LOVE U!

Comment: Good :-)  No kissing please, unless your're a lady but you may love the ones you're with ;-)

Comment: How am I able to put a check for scrolling down to determine if I am at the last item, do not scroll any further? Ex. For scrolling up, I put the condition, if (listView1.Top != 0)

Comment: If have added code to check, also to allow for multiple columns, although that is not needed for you..